# Tic Tac Toe game in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tic-tac-toe

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout, getLine)

data Tile   = EmptyTile | X | O
data Player = Player1 | Player2

instance Show Tile where
    show EmptyTile = " "
    show X         = "X"
    show O         = "O"

type Board    = (Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile)

emptyBoard :: Board
emptyBoard = (EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile)

put :: Board -> Tile -> Int -> Maybe Board
put (EmptyTile,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) t 0 = Just (t,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
put (a,EmptyTile,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) t 1 = Just (a,t,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
put (a,b,EmptyTile,d,e,f,g,h,i) t 2 = Just (a,b,t,d,e,f,g,h,i)
put (a,b,c,EmptyTile,e,f,g,h,i) t 3 = Just (a,b,c,t,e,f,g,h,i)
put (a,b,c,d,EmptyTile,f,g,h,i) t 4 = Just (a,b,c,d,t,f,g,h,i)
put (a,b,c,d,e,EmptyTile,g,h,i) t 5 = Just (a,b,c,d,e,t,g,h,i)
put (a,b,c,d,e,f,EmptyTile,h,i) t 6 = Just (a,b,c,d,e,f,t,h,i)
put (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,EmptyTile,i) t 7 = Just (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,t,i)
put (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,EmptyTile) t 8 = Just (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,t)
put _ _ _ = Nothing

checkWinner :: Board -> Maybe Player
checkWinner (X,X,X,_,_,_,_,_,_) = Just Player1
checkWinner (_,_,_,X,X,X,_,_,_) = Just Player1
checkWinner (_,_,_,_,_,_,X,X,X) = Just Player1
checkWinner (X,_,_,X,_,_,X,_,_) = Just Player1
checkWinner (_,X,_,_,X,_,_,X,_) = Just Player1
checkWinner (_,_,X,_,_,X,_,_,X) = Just Player1
checkWinner (X,_,_,_,X,_,_,_,X) = Just Player1
checkWinner (_,_,X,_,X,_,X,_,_) = Just Player1
checkWinner (O,O,O,_,_,_,_,_,_) = Just Player2
checkWinner (_,_,_,O,O,O,_,_,_) = Just Player2
checkWinner (O,_,_,O,_,_,O,_,_) = Just Player2
checkWinner (_,O,_,_,O,_,_,O,_) = Just Player2
checkWinner (_,_,O,_,_,O,_,_,O) = Just Player2
checkWinner (_,_,_,_,_,_,O,O,O) = Just Player2
checkWinner (O,_,_,_,O,_,_,_,O) = Just Player2
checkWinner (_,_,O,_,O,_,O,_,_) = Just Player2
checkWinner _ = Nothing

checkFull :: Board -> Bool
checkFull (EmptyTile,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_) = False
checkFull (_,EmptyTile,_,_,_,_,_,_,_) = False
checkFull (_,_,EmptyTile,_,_,_,_,_,_) = False
checkFull (_,_,_,EmptyTile,_,_,_,_,_) = False
checkFull (_,_,_,_,EmptyTile,_,_,_,_) = False
checkFull (_,_,_,_,_,EmptyTile,_,_,_) = False
checkFull (_,_,_,_,_,_,EmptyTile,_,_) = False
checkFull (_,_,_,_,_,_,_,EmptyTile,_) = False
checkFull (_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,EmptyTile) = False
checkFull _= True


getTile :: Board -> Int -> Tile
getTile (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 0 = a
getTile (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 1 = b
getTile (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 2 = c
getTile (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 3 = d
getTile (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 4 = e
getTile (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 5 = f
getTile (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 6 = g
getTile (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 7 = h
getTile (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 8 = i

compMove :: Board -> IO (Board)
compMove b = do
    pos <- getRandomEmpty b
    let (Just b') = put b O pos
    return b'

getRandomEmpty :: Board -> IO Int
getRandomEmpty b = do
    pos <- randomRIO (0,8)
    let t = getTile b pos
    case t of
        EmptyTile -> return pos
        _         -> getRandomEmpty b

printBoard :: Board -> IO ()
printBoard (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) = do
    putStrLn ("|" ++ show a ++ "|" ++ show b ++ "|" ++ show c ++ "|")
    putStrLn ("|" ++ show d ++ "|" ++ show e ++ "|" ++ show f ++ "|")
    putStrLn ("|" ++ show g ++ "|" ++ show h ++ "|" ++ show i ++ "|")
    putStrLn "---------"

printTileNumbers :: IO ()
printTileNumbers  = do
    putStrLn "|0|1|2|"
    putStrLn "|3|4|5|"
    putStrLn "|6|7|8|"
    putStrLn ""


prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt s = do
    putStr s
    hFlush stdout
    getLine

main = do
    putStrLn "This is classic tic tac toe game."
    putStrLn "In order to play, you need to put a number between 0 and 8"
    putStrLn "This table shows tile numbers"
    printTileNumbers
    printBoard emptyBoard
    playGame emptyBoard
    where
        playGame b = do
            playerchoice <- prompt "Make a move: "
            let newboard = put b X (read playerchoice)
            case newboard of
                Nothing -> do
                            putStrLn "Invalid move."
                            playGame b
                Just b' ->
                            case checkWinner b' of
                                Just Player1 -> putStrLn "You win!"
                                _            -> if checkFull b' then
                                                    putStrLn "Tie"
                                                else do
                                                    b'' <- compMove b'
                                                    printBoard b''
                                                    case checkWinner b'' of
                                                        Just Player2 -> putStrLn "You Lose!"
                                                        _            -> if checkFull b'' then
                                                                            putStrLn "Tie"
                                                                        else
                                                                            playGame b''
```

Comment: Is it suppose to be indented that way ? or did it occur when you pasted the code ?

Comment: @JaDogg It is supposed to be indented that way. But it is possible to decrease the indentation a little bit, I will fix that now.

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/88576/9357)

Answer (score 5):

I have only written Haskell once before, and then I did not write anything nearly as complicated as Tic Tac Toe. I can only give you certain suggestions, I am not able to tell you exactly how to do it in Haskell.

#### The type

```
type Board    = (Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile)
```

In most of the code I write, I try to write it as flexible as possible. Here you have hard-coded nine tiles. What if you wanted to make a 4x4 Tic Tac Toe game instead? Or a 5x5? Or a NxN and let the user decide the size?

Use a 2-dimensional array instead.

#### put

```
put :: Board -> Tile -> Int -> Maybe Board
put (EmptyTile,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) t 0 = Just (t,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
put (a,EmptyTile,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) t 1 = Just (a,t,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
put (a,b,EmptyTile,d,e,f,g,h,i) t 2 = Just (a,b,t,d,e,f,g,h,i)
...
put (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,EmptyTile,i) t 7 = Just (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,t,i)
put (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,EmptyTile) t 8 = Just (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,t)
put _ _ _ = Nothing
```

Again, if using a 2D-array, you should be able to loop through all the tiles here and check the put for each position. Or better yet, as the `Int` tells you exactly what index to change, you should only change the value on that specific index. Study up on arrays in Haskell and you should be able to make it better by only changing one index in the array.

#### checkWinner

First of all, this contains duplicated logic. Once for `X` and once for `Y`, that part can be extracted.

Additionally, there's a little trick that can be used when checking for winners in Tic-Tac-Toe. The idea is to start at a certain position, and then loop and change the row and column indices by 1 and check the next position, repeatedly until you go outside of the board range.

#### checkFull

Again, use a for-loop.

#### getTile

Again, use an array and grab a specific index.

#### The last part of your code

That's a lot of indentation! A looooot of indentation! Try to find a way to reduce that. Put more if-statements on the same indentation level? Switch if's with else's? Sorry I can't provide detailed help here. All I can say is: Yes, that is a code smell.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Just a little note, Haskell doesn't have for-loops, it only have recursions.

Comment: @yasar Then use recursions :)

Answer (score 4):

### User experience

When someone wins, print the winning board configuration before exiting.  Just accepting the input and printing "You win!" leaves an unsatisfactory feeling.

Regardless of how it is represented internally, for the user interface, the board should be indexed in a way that mimics a computer number keypad:

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

### Implementation

There's a lot of brute-force enumeration of all the cases.  I suppose a 3 × 3 board is small enough to allow that.

---

`data Tile` and `data Player` feel redundant.  I would just define `type Tile = Maybe Player`.  In addition, `Player` should derive `Eq` (and possibly `Show` as well).

```
data Player = Player1 | Player2 deriving (Eq, Show)

type Tile   = Maybe Player

tile :: Tile -> String
tile (Just Player1) = "X"
tile (Just Player2) = "O"
tile Nothing        = " "
```

---

A few of your functions are too procedural.  For example, instead of `printBoard :: Board -> IO()`, it would be better to make `Board` an instance of `Show`, such that `show board` produces a `String`.

```
data Board  = Board [Tile]
instance Show Board where
    show (Board b) = intercalate "\n" $ map ((extercalate "|") . (map tile)) $ reverse $ rows (Board b)
        where extercalate delim list = delim ++ (intercalate delim list) ++ delim

emptyBoard :: Board
emptyBoard = Board $ replicate (size^2) Nothing
    where size = 3

-- indexing scheme for get and put
tileGuide :: String
tileGuide =
    intercalate "\n" ["|7|8|9|",
                      "|4|5|6|",
                      "|1|2|3|"]
```

Another example of procedural thinking is in the name `checkFull`.  A better name would be `isFull`.

```
isFull :: Board -> Bool
isFull (Board b) = not $ any isNothing b
```

---

There's a bit of asymmetry in the names `getTile` and `put`.  Personally, I would just choose `get` and `put`.

For `put`, the `board` parameter should go last.  That lets you write a chained expression like `fromJust $ put Player2 3 $ fromJust $ put Player1 6 emptyBoard`.  In your original form, such an expression would be nasty.

```
get :: Int -> Board -> Tile
get pos (Board board)
    | pos < 1 || pos > 9 = Nothing
    | otherwise          = board !! (pos - 1)

put :: Player -> Int -> Board -> Maybe Board
put player pos (Board board)
    | pos < 1 || pos > 9                = Nothing
    | isNothing $ get pos (Board board) = Just newBoard
    | otherwise                         = Nothing
    where
        update i (x:xs) y
          | i == 0    = y:xs
          | otherwise = x : update (i - 1) xs y
        newBoard = Board $ update (pos - 1) board $ Just player

rows :: Board -> [[Tile]]
rows (Board b) = chunk 3 b 
    where
        -- Or use chunk from Data.List.Split
        chunk _ [] = []
        chunk n xs = (take n xs) : (chunk n $ drop n xs)
```

---

As with `checkFull` → `isFull`, you should rename `checkWinner` to `winner`.

Something suspicious happened with your copy-and-paste code: the cases for `O` are in a weird order.

With a list representation, you can use `!!` indexing.

```
winner :: Board -> Maybe Player         
winner (Board board) = winner' $ streaks board
    where
        allSame [_]      = True
        allSame (x:y:zs) = (x == y) && allSame (y:zs)

        streaks b = map (map (b !!)) [
            [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],    -- rows
            [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],    -- columns
            [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6] ]              -- diagonals

        winner' xs 
            | isNothing w = Nothing
            | otherwise   = head $ fromJust w
            where w = find allSame xs
```

---

To finish, here are the additional imports to make the code above work:

```
import Data.List (find, intercalate)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust, isNothing)
```

… and some minor modifications to `main`:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "This is classic tic tac toe game."
    putStrLn "In order to play, you need to put a number between 1 and 9"
    putStrLn "This table shows tile numbers"
    putStrLn $ tileGuide
    putStrLn ""
    putStrLn $ show $ emptyBoard
    playGame $ emptyBoard
    where
        playGame b = do
            playerchoice <- prompt "Make a move: "
            let newboard = put Player1 (read playerchoice) b
            case newboard of
            Nothing -> do
                putStrLn "Invalid move."
                playGame b
            Just b' ->
                case winner b' of
                Just Player1 -> do
                                    putStrLn $ show b'
                                    putStrLn "You win!"
                _            -> if isFull b' then
                                    putStrLn "Tie"
                                else do
                                    b'' <- compMove b'
                                    putStrLn $ show b''
                                    case winner b'' of
                                    Just Player2 -> putStrLn "You Lose!"
                                    _            -> if isFull b'' then
                                                        putStrLn "Tie"
                                                    else
                                                        playGame b''
```

Comment: In my opinion, if there is a clear pattern, then no board is "small enough" to allow a brute-force enumeration of all the cases. I'd always go with using the pattern to enumerate the cases.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg The `streaks` list in my proposed code, for example, is still a kind of brute-force enumeration. I challenge you to write simpler code to look for streaks in the horizontal, vertical, and diagonal cases. It isn't worth the trouble for 3x3.

Comment: I never said my way would be simpler. I'd still prefer it though. You have your right to disagree.