# Tic Tac Toe game in haskell follow up

Tags: haskell, tic-tac-toe

This is a follow-up question of this one: [Tic Tac Toe game in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88497/tic-tac-toe-game-in-haskell)

I have revised my code. How does it look now?

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout, getLine)
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.Array

data Tile   = EmptyTile | X | O deriving (Eq)
data Player = Player1 | Player2

showTile :: Tile -> String
showTile EmptyTile = " "
showTile X         = "X"
showTile O         = "O"

showBoard :: Board -> String
showBoard b = let bstr = fmap showTile b
                  blist = boardAsList bstr
              in  unlines [intercalate "|" row | row <- blist]
              where
                boardAsList b = [[b!(x,y) | y <- [1,2,3]] | x <- [1,2,3]]

type Board = Array (Int,Int) Tile

emptyBoard :: Board
emptyBoard = array ((1,1),(3,3)) [((x,y), EmptyTile) | x <- [1,2,3], y <- [1,2,3]]

put :: Board -> Tile -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Board
put b t x y = case b!(x,y) of
                EmptyTile -> Just (b // [((x,y), t)])
                _         -> Nothing

p1wins, p2wins :: Board -> Bool
p1wins b = tileWins b X
p2wins b = tileWins b O

tileWins :: Board -> Tile -> Bool
tileWins b t = 
   any (\row -> all (\col -> b!(row,col) == t) [1..3]) [1..3] ||
   any (\col -> all (\row -> b!(row,col) == t) [1..3]) [1..3] ||
   all (\rc -> b!(rc,rc) == t) [1..3] ||
   all (\rc -> b!(rc,4-rc) == t) [1..3]

checkFull :: Board -> Bool
checkFull b = all (\row -> all (\col -> b!(row, col) /= EmptyTile) [1..3]) [1..3]

compMove :: Board -> IO (Board)
compMove b = do
    (row, col) <- getRandomEmpty b
    let (Just b') = put b O row col
    return b'

getRandomEmpty :: Board -> IO (Int, Int)
getRandomEmpty b = do
    col <- randomRIO (1,3)
    row <- randomRIO (1,3)
    case b!(row, col) of
        EmptyTile -> return (row, col)
        _         -> getRandomEmpty b

prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt s = do
    putStr s
    hFlush stdout
    getLine

showTileNumbers :: String
showTileNumbers  = (unlines
                   [intercalate "|" ["(" ++ show x ++ "," ++ show y ++ ")" |
                   y <- [1,2,3]] | x <- [1,2,3]])

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "This is classic tic tac toe game."
    putStrLn "In order to play, you need to put a number between 0 and 8"
    putStrLn "This table shows tile numbers"
    putStrLn showTileNumbers
    putStrLn $ showBoard emptyBoard
    playTurn emptyBoard Player1
    where
        playTurn b Player1 = do
            row <- prompt "Row: "
            col <- prompt "Col: "
            let newboard = put b X (read row) (read col)
            case newboard of
                Nothing -> do
                            putStrLn "Invalid move."
                            playTurn b Player1
                Just b' -> if p1wins b' then
                                putStrLn "You win"
                            else
                                playTurnIfNotTie b' Player2
        playTurn b Player2 = do
            b' <- compMove b
            putStrLn $ showBoard b'
            if p2wins b' then
                putStrLn "You Lose!"
            else
                playTurnIfNotTie b' Player1

        playTurnIfNotTie b p = if checkFull b then
                                  putStrLn "Tie."
                               else
                                  playTurn b p
```

Answer (score 2):

With the new board representation, the brute-force pattern matching is gone, which is good.  Still, I personally prefer the 1–9 numbering for simpler user interface — perhaps a translation function could be implemented.  Note that you forgot to adjust the introductory message for the new coordinate system.

Instead of the `showTile` function, you should use the standard `Show` typeclass:

```
instance Show Tile where
    show EmptyTile = " "
    show X         = "X"
    show O         = "O"
```

In `showBoard` you used both `let … in` and `where`.  Pick one or the other (I prefer `where`).

As mentioned in my [previous answer](/a/88597/9357), all of your functions that accept a `Board` should place the `board` parameter last, since the board is what they all operate on.  With `tileWins :: Tile -> Board`, for example, you can define `p1wins = tileWins X` using the point-free style.

`data Player = Player1 | Player2` isn't doing anything useful for you.  You are hard-coding the `Player1` ↔︎ `X` and the `Player2` ↔︎ `O` correspondence all over the place, in `main`, `p1wins`, `p2wins`, and `compMove`.

With this second version, then, I would say that the greatest improvement can be made in handling the two players.  Here is my suggestion:

```
humanTurn :: Tile -> Board -> IO Board
humanTurn t b = do
    putStrLn $ showBoard b
    move
    where
        move = do
            row <- prompt "Row: "
            col <- prompt "Col: "
            let newboard = put b t (read row) (read col)
            case newboard of
                Nothing -> do
                            putStrLn "Invalid move."
                            move
                Just b' -> return b'

computerTurn :: Tile -> Board -> IO Board
computerTurn t b = do
    (row, col) <- getRandomEmpty b 
    let (Just b') = put b t row col
    return b'

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "This is the classic tic tac toe game."
    putStrLn "Enter the coordinates for each move according to this scheme:"
    putStrLn showTileNumbers
    play player1 player2 emptyBoard
    where
        player1 = (X, humanTurn, "You win!")
        player2 = (O, computerTurn, "You lose.")
        play p@(tile, turn, winMsg) p' b = do
            b' <- turn tile b
            if tileWins tile b' then do
                putStrLn $ showBoard b'
                putStrLn winMsg
            else if checkFull b' then do
                putStrLn $ showBoard b'
                putStrLn "Tie."
            else
                play p' p b'
```

This turns `main` into a leaner state machine.  As evidence of the superiority of this design, observe that you can make a human-*vs.*-human game simply by changing two lines to…

```
       player1 = (X, humanTurn, "X wins.")
       player2 = (O, humanTurn, "O wins.")
```