# TicTacToe game in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tic-tac-toe

As a beginner, I tried to implement TicTacToe in Haskell. How can I improve my code?

I have refactored my code: [General TicTacToe in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98754/general-tictactoe-in-haskell)

**Utils**

```
module Data.List.Utils where 

import Data.List (intersperse)

surround :: a -> [a] -> [a]
surround x ys = x : intersperse x ys ++ [x]

nth :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
nth _ _ [] = []
nth 0 f (x:xs) = f x : xs
nth n f (x:xs) = x : nth (n - 1) f xs
```

**TicTacToe**

```
module TicTacToe where

import Data.List (transpose)
import Data.Foldable (asum)
import Data.List.Utils (nth, surround)

data Tile = Empty | O | X deriving (Show, Eq)

showTile :: Tile -> String
showTile Empty = " "
showTile O     = "O"
showTile X     = "X"

type Board = [[ Tile ]]

showBoard :: Board -> String
showBoard = unlines
          . surround vert
          . map (concat . surround horiz . map showTile)

    where vert  = "+-+-+-+"
          horiz = "|"

whoWon :: Board -> Maybe Tile
whoWon xs = asum . map winner $ diag : anti : rows ++ cols

    where rows = xs
          cols = transpose xs
          diag = zipWith (!!) xs [0..]
          anti = zipWith (!!) xs [2,1..]

          winner [O, O, O] = Just O
          winner [X, X, X] = Just X
          winner _         = Nothing 

fillTile :: Int -> Int -> Tile -> Board -> Board
fillTile row col = nth row . nth col . const

isOver :: Board -> Bool
isOver = all (all (/= Empty))

overMsg :: Maybe Tile -> String
overMsg (Just x) = "Winner: " ++ (showTile x)
overMsg Nothing  = "Game Over! No winner."

inRange :: Int -> Bool
inRange x = x >= 0 && x <= 2

gameLoop :: Tile -> Board -> IO ()
gameLoop player board
    | isOver board || winner /= Nothing = putStrLn $ overMsg winner
    | otherwise    = do

        putStrLn $ showBoard board
        putStrLn $ "Now player " ++ showTile player

        putStr "Row: "
        row <- fmap read getLine

        putStr "Col: "
        col <- fmap read getLine

        if inRange row && inRange col && (board !! row !! col == Empty)

            then gameLoop (if player == O then X else O) $
                     fillTile row col player board

            else do
                putStrLn "Invalid position, please try again."
                gameLoop player board

    where winner = whoWon board

startBoard :: Board
startBoard = replicate 3 (replicate 3 Empty)

main = gameLoop O startBoard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts about your Tic-Tac-Toe version.

You made a **confusion between Tile and Player**. You assume a Player is the same as a Tile but it is not. A Tile can be Empty but a Player cannot be empty. You should separate these two notions. It will make your declarations clearer on what you expect. What if I call "gameLoop Empty startBoard" ?

The **putStr function does not flush** immediately its output in a compiled program. Your program asks the user for a row and a column and displays these labels after the user inputs.

Is it natural to ask for the row before the column ?

You have **intertwined the game logic with the user interface** in the gameLoop function. What will you do if you want to implement a computer player ? Or have a GUI to play the game ? You will have to patch your gameLoop function though the game logic has not changed.

Your solution is locked to the fact that **your board is a 3×3 grid with a 3 tiles win**. For example, your inRange functions works for row indices AND column indices, which are not the same. You use the constants 2 and 3 in your code (inRange, startBoard and whoWon), but nothing implies a relation between them. The 3 rows and 3 columns are characteristics of the Board, not of your functions.

**Messages could be more specific**. When you tell the user "Invalid position", there’s no way to know if it’s because the coordinates are out of bounds or because the tile has already been played.

Note: there are many Tic-Tac-Toe game related questions on CodeReview, you should take a look at:

- [Tic Tac Toe game in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88497/tic-tac-toe-game-in-haskell) (a brute first attempt)
- [Tic Tac Toe game in haskell follow up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88576/tic-tac-toe-game-in-haskell-follow-up) (its follow up)
- [TicTacToe in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68345/tictactoe-in-haskell) (a version using Lens)
- [m,n,k-game (i.e. generalized tic-tac-toe)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90171/m-n-k-game-i-e-generalized-tic-tac-toe) (its generalization)